# preg_match for validate custom pattern

Tags: javascript, php, preg-match

i need regular expression for  validate string With this pattern:

*33(or any number)*13(or any number)#

Could anyone guide me through preg_match

Comment: have you tried anything yet? any effort? and what do you meant by (or any number)

Comment: show the exemplary string

Comment: ^\*[1-9]+\*[1-9]+\#$ ,any number mean any number between two star

Comment: `^*[1-9]+*[1-9]+\#$` - it's a pattern, how about the exemplary string? Also, does this `*33` mean the exact match of doubled `3`?. Add more context

Comment: no 33 is Just one example,
The numbers should be between star and sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/\*([0-9]+)\*([0-9]+)#/", "*3398*1376#",$match);
print_r($match);
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript or php preg_match?? you taged both.

```
$pattern = "/\*\d+\*\d+#/";
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fLX